# Progress bar failure with upload form in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have such a code on my upload.php:

The statement which calls javascript is shown below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 
//

//show the progress bar only if a file field was clicked
    var show_bar = 0;
    $('input[type="file"]').click(function(){
        show_bar = 1;
    });

//show iframe on form submit
    $("ajax-contact-form").submit(function(){

        if (show_bar === 1) { 
            $('#upload_frame').show();
            function set () {
                $('#upload_frame').attr('src','upload_frame.php?up_id=<?php echo $up_id; ?>');
            }
            setTimeout(set);
        }
    });
//

});

</script>
```

And this is the form code statements:

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" action=""  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">

    <INPUT type="text" name="name" value="Material Name:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Material Name:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='Material Name:' ) this.value=''">
    <div class="clear"></div><br>
    Choose a file to upload:<br />

<!--APC hidden field-->
    <input type="hidden" name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" id="progress_key" value="<?php echo $up_id; ?>"/>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<!---->

    <input name="file" type="file" id="file" size="3000"/>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<!--Include the iframe-->
    <br />
    <iframe id="upload_frame" name="upload_frame" frameborder="0" border="0" src="" scrolling="no" scrollbar="no" > </iframe>

<!---->

    <INPUT class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                  <div class="clear"></div>
  </form>
```

But when I upload a file, the progress bar is not shown on the page. Although I put right addresses, it gives an error.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks...

Comment: First quick debug point: Does your server have APC installed? This upload script uses it.

Comment: And what error does it give?

Comment: Actually I use Azure web server Lee :)

Comment: It gives a logical error. I cannot see the progress bar. :)

Comment: Web server is irrelevant. The upload php script uses the APC extension to track upload progress. So you need to check APC is installed and enabled.

Comment: Ho can I check this? Can I install this manually into my web server? If I can, where should I deploy the installation?

Comment: Upload a file containing     <?php phpinfo(); ?> and nothing else. Access it and look for the APC section. If it's not there, it's not installed. I have no specific experience with Azure though.

Comment: Will I install it to the same root with upload.php? And what will be the name of the file?

Comment: Doesn't matter where you put it or what you call it. Just needs to be accessible by your browser.

Comment: Okay, so what will be the name of file?

Comment: ahh, sorry, it wasn't matter how do I call it. :D

Comment: www.example.com/name-of-file.php

Comment: `$("#ajax-contact-form")` missing `#` for id selector and if you want to change only iframes src then why you are using form submit.

Comment: Lee, actually nothing has happened, and nothing has changed.

Comment: Jai, actually I directly got the code from somewhere else, and I want to implement this for my purpose. But even I put id selector, still it doesn't work :(

Comment: Does the server even support php? You need to get PHP and APC installed before this even has a chance of working. Contact your hosting provider for assistance.

Comment: of course, Lee. :) PHP works. :D I want a progress bar for my website. :)

Comment: how can I install APC?

Comment: This method will only work if your server has APC. I don't know how else I can say this. Make sure it does if you want to use this script, and then come back.

Comment: You cannot if you're on a shared server. Your hosting provider has to do it.

Comment: Lee, I use an Azure Web Server. And the provider is Microsoft. How can I manage this? And also I can manage my own server in Azure. How can I install APC? :D

Comment: That is outside the scope of StackOverflow. Contact Microsoft or try on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 1):

theres a syntax error here:

```
     setTimeout(set);
```

the syntax for `setTimeout()` is `setTimeout(function,milliseconds,lang)`

Comment: Can you give me a brief example? :)

Comment: as I looked into my code, there is already a function called set. And delay isn't necessary.

Comment: because if there would be an error, I would see a syntax error on debugging.

Comment: then use this: `set()`

Comment: like lee said you will need APC installed which is beyond the scope of stackoverflow, sorry

Comment: Thank you user3549636 :)